# Getting an object and yours attributes in select tag - angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have this a this json:

```
{
  "OfferFieldList":
    {
       "Title":"someTitle",
       "Id":"someId"
    },
   "OfferFieldList":
    {
       "Title":"someTitle",
       "Id":"someId"
    }
}
```

and i have this select tag:

```
<select formControlName="offerFielId" (change)="changeValueType($event.target.value)" #offerFielId >
    <option value="{{offerFile.id}}" *ngFor="let offerFile of OfferFieldList">{{ offerFile.title }}</option>
</select>
```

when I execute it all work well, i can get the title or id in my changeValueType() method, but i need get the all object and when i try get the object (using this code):

```
<select formControlName="offerFielId" (change)="changeValueType($event.target.value)" #offerFielId >
    <option value="{{offerFile}}" *ngFor="let offerFile of OfferFieldList">{{ offerFile.title }}</option>
</select>
```

but when i do that and try access my object properties

```
changeValueType(paramer) {
    this.myVar = paramer.title;
}
```

the title property is 'undefined'.

so i tried console it

```
changeValueType(paramer) {
        console.dir(paramer)
    }
```

i get a value like "[object Object]", so i try se what i have into thats objects with:

```
console.dir(paramerOfChangeValueTypeMethod));
```

but have nothing into that.

I try too send just the value and i get something like "changeValueType"input.input.ng-untouched.ng-pristine.ng-invalid"

so i try send just the $event and i get i big object, and navigatting into this big object i found the value property but there have another "[object Object]"

i tried too do it

```
<select formControlName="offerFielId" (change)="changeOfferField({{ offerField.title }})">
        <option value="{{ offerField.id }}" *ngFor="let offerField of offerFieldList">{{ offerField.title }}</option>
</select>
```

but the change propertie dont accept the {{someValue}} syntax

i shereaded at google but i every solution i founded dont work, work for they, but not to me, i cant get that object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **`[ngModel]`** and watch for its changes via **`(ngModelChange)`** event to perform your operation\manipulation., and also use **`[ngValue]`** instead of `value`.

See [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zP6eYMakM0hihHJs1XLZ?p=preview)